Animating a Patterned UIView to Mimic Progress Bar
I'm trying to create a progress bar animation in Swift. I designed a patterned image to simulate progress but can't directly apply this animation to a UIProgressView. Instead, I placed a UIView on top to mimic this behavior.
I made a symmetric pic: green background, with dark green horizontal lines.
As I understood, since I cannot attach it on UIProgressBar, I added a UIView to mimic ProgressBar.
The idea is to have something like this:

Here's my current setup:
import UIKit

class SideMenuButtons: UIViewController {
    var progressOverlayView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var energyReloadingIndicator: UIProgressView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        progressOverlayView = UIView()
        if let patternImage = UIImage(named: "striped-pattern-repeated") {
            progressOverlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: patternImage)
        } else {
            progressOverlayView.backgroundColor = .red
        }
        energyReloadingIndicator.addSubview(progressOverlayView)
        updateProgressOverlayViewWidth()
    }
    
    private func updateProgressOverlayViewWidth() {
        let progress = CGFloat(energyReloadingIndicator.progress)
        let maxWidth = energyReloadingIndicator.frame.width
        let overlayWidth = maxWidth * progress
        let overlayHeight = energyReloadingIndicator.frame.height
        progressOverlayView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: overlayWidth, height: overlayHeight)
    }
}

How can I animate the pattern in progressOverlayView to achieve a continuous moving effect?

One solution would be need to take 3 images of progress bar like continuous. Need to take timer of 0.2 seconds and change the image after each interval. And pit it in the UIViewAnimation block would achieve that you want.

You can download gif image from here https://icons8.com/preloaders/en/horizontal, and load gif image in your code

Let's look at one approach that does not require an animated gif, or a pattern image..
We can use a UIBezierPath with a CAShapeLayer to create the pattern in a custom view subclass:

and we can set the background color of the view with the "between the lines" color:

Now we can use CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x") to "slide" that layer to the left. We create the lines path to be wider than the view so we don't see a gap on the right (ignore the "hiccup" in this animation, it's only there because it's a partial capture):

Your original image also appears to have a slight gradient, so we can overlay a translucent gradient for that appearance:

Now we can create a custom "progress" view by embedding that animated shape view in a "container" view, and adjust the width of the container to reflect the progress:

Here is some sample code...

AnimatedPatternView: all of the size, color, speed, etc properties are at the top to make it easy to adjust them to your liking:
class AnimatedPatternView: UIView {
    
    private let angledLinesShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let overlayGradLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    // let's put all of our appearance variables here
    //  in one place, to make it easier to adjust them
    
    // this will be the amount of time (in seconds) that the
    //  animation takes to slide "one tile" to the left
    private let animSpeed: Double = 0.5
    
    // "tile" width
    private let tileWidth: CGFloat = 40.0
    
    // we want an angled line, not the full width
    private let angledLineBottomOffset: CGFloat = 32.0
    
    // thickness of the lines
    private let angledLineThickness: CGFloat = 14.0
    
    // the angled-line and "space between" colors
    private let angledLineColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.557, green: 0.420, blue: 0.863, alpha: 1.0)
    private let spaceBetweenColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.624, green: 0.494, blue: 0.886, alpha: 1.0)
    
    // soft overlay gradient
    private let overlayGradientColors: [CGColor] = [
        UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor,
        UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.1).cgColor,
        UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.05).cgColor,
    ]
    
    // gradient angle
    private let gradStartPoint: CGPoint = .init(x: 0.250, y: 0.0)
    private let gradEndPoint: CGPoint = .init(x: 0.750, y: 1.0)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        self.backgroundColor = spaceBetweenColor
        
        angledLinesShapeLayer.strokeColor = angledLineColor.cgColor
        
        angledLinesShapeLayer.lineWidth = angledLineThickness
        angledLinesShapeLayer.lineCap = .square

        overlayGradLayer.colors = overlayGradientColors
        overlayGradLayer.startPoint = gradStartPoint
        overlayGradLayer.endPoint = gradEndPoint
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(angledLinesShapeLayer)
        self.layer.addSublayer(overlayGradLayer)

        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.clipsToBounds = true

    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        var x: CGFloat = 0.0
        while x < bounds.width + tileWidth {
            bez.move(to: .init(x: x, y: bounds.minY))
            bez.addLine(to: .init(x: x + angledLineBottomOffset, y: bounds.maxY))
            x += tileWidth
        }
        angledLinesShapeLayer.path = bez.cgPath

        // gradient layer needs to match the view bounds
        overlayGradLayer.frame = bounds
        
        angledLinesShapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = -tileWidth
        animation.duration = animSpeed
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity
        angledLinesShapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "stripeAnim")
    }
}


EnergyProgressView: view subclass that uses the AnimatedPatternView and a container view to simulate a progress bar:
class EnergyProgressView: UIView {
    public var progress: Float {
        set { _progress = newValue }
        get { return _progress }
    }
    private var _progress: Float = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            wConstraint.isActive = false
            wConstraint = containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: CGFloat(_progress))
            wConstraint.isActive = true
        }
    }
    
    private let animPatternView = AnimatedPatternView()
    private let containerView = UIView()
    
    // this will control the width of the container
    //  using progress as a percentage of the width
    private var wConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        animPatternView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(animPatternView)
        self.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true

        // we'll be modifying the width of containerView to reflect the progress
        wConstraint = containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            wConstraint,
            
            // even though animPatternView is a subview of containerView
            //  we constrain animPatternView to self so it doesn't resize
            //  when the progress changes
            animPatternView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            animPatternView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            animPatternView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            animPatternView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    }
    
    func setProgress(_ p: Float, animated: Bool = false) {
        _progress = p
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }

}


ViewController: example view controller with the custom progress bar and a slider to update the progress:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let myProgressView = EnergyProgressView()
    
    // let's add a label and a slider so we can dynamically set the progress
    let pctLabel = UILabel()
    let slider = UISlider()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        myProgressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(myProgressView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myProgressView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            myProgressView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            myProgressView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            myProgressView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0),
        ])

        pctLabel.textAlignment = .center
        
        pctLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(pctLabel)
        slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(slider)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pctLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myProgressView.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            pctLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pctLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            slider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pctLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            slider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSlider(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        slider.value = 0.5
        myProgressView.progress = 0.5
        updatePctLabel()
    }
    @objc func handleSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        myProgressView.progress = sender.value
        updatePctLabel()
    }
    func updatePctLabel() {
        let v = myProgressView.progress
        pctLabel.text = String(format: "%0.2f %%", v * 100.0)
    }
}


Please Note: this is Example Code Only!!! It should be used as a learning tool, and should not be considered "Production Ready."

Dear @DonMag, if I could hug you or send you flowers - I would definitely do so :D Big-big thanks!

Basically, we can add gif image in image view, and achieve animation.
1.
Like this answer
GIF Image to add
let jeremyGif = UIImage.gifImageWithName("loader")
loaderImageView = UIImageView(image: jeremyGif)
loaderImageView?.contentMode = .left
loaderImageView?.clipsToBounds = true

As you said, take a timer
2.
timerForIncreaseProgress = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(increaseProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



 @objc func increaseProgress() {
        progress = progress + 0.05
        progressView.progress = progress
        let maxWidth = progressView.frame.width
        let overlayWidth = Float(maxWidth) * progress
        loaderImageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Double(overlayWidth), height: 13.0)
        print("progressOverlayView.width \(progressOverlayView.frame.width)")
        if progress >= 1 {
            timerForIncreaseProgress?.invalidate()
            timerForIncreaseProgress = nil
        }
    }

Hope, it would help you
